# Timing issues considerations when using WeakMap from EcmaScript

Tags: javascript, garbage-collection, ecmascript-6, weakmap

What is the proper usage of the WeakMap in JavaScript? What kind of timing issues may occur when I use it? IN particular, I am wondering what would happen in the following situation:

```
var wm1 = new WeakMap()
var o1 = {},
o2 = function(){},
o3 = window;
// in other method:
    wm1.set(o1, 37);
    wm1.set(o2, "azerty");
    if (wm1.has(o2)) {
    //Garbage collection happen here, objects from wm1 may no longer exists
    Console.log(wm1.get(o2)) // what will happen here? just undefined? null?
    }
```

how GC will affect WeakMaps?

**Update**: my bad, I missed the fact that you can't have string as keys in WeakMap, my question does not make if I take into account that fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`WeakMap`s are explicitly designed to not exhibit the least observable garbage collection behaviour. There will be absolutely zero issues.

In your specific situtation, as long as you hold a reference to the object or to the function (through the live variables `o1` and `o2` that are still on the stack), you will be able to find them in the `WeakMap` or `WeakSet`. As soon as you don't hold a reference to them any more, and nobody does, they are eligible for garbage collection (just as usual) - and given that, nobody will be able to try to look them up in the collection.

Comment: @VitaliyGanzha: That's the reason why you can't use strings as keys in a weak collection :-)